# Clear icon displaying on all elements in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to display a remove icon on a grid display that the users mouse is hovering over.

```
this.state = {
      action: [],
}
```

```
<div>
    {this.state.action.map((value, index) => {
    return (
    <div key={index} onMouseEnter={this.removeElementIcon} onMouseLeave={this.hideRemoveElementIcon} className={classes.gridClass}>
        <Grid className={classes.marginGrid}>
            <Paper className={classes.paddingPaper}>
                <Typography variant={"h5"}>{value}</Typography>
                <Typography component={"p"}>{value}</Typography>
            </Paper>
        </Grid>
        {this.state.removeElementIcon ?
        <IconButton className={classes.removeElement} color={"secondary"} arial-label={"remove element"} onClick={()=> this.removeElement(value)}>
            <ClearIcon color={"error"} />
        </IconButton>
        : null}
    </div>
```

I've tried just returning some jsx from the method itself.

```
removeElementIcon = () => {
  return ({
      this.state.removeElementIcon ?
      <IconButton className={classes.removeElement} color={"secondary"}
                        arial-label={"remove element"} onClick={() => this.removeElement(value)}>
              <ClearIcon color={"error"}/>
            </IconButton> :
          null
  });
```

Instead of:

```
removeElementIcon = () => {
    this.setState({removeElementIcon: true});
};

hideRemoveElementIcon = () => {
    this.setState({removeElementIcon: false});
};
```

Instead of just displaying the clear icon on one element it displays on all elements.

Comment: Hi Ezrab, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain item `index` in state,

```
this.state = {
   action: [],
   hoverIndex: '',
}
```

Pass the `index` to your `removeElementIcon` function,

```
<div 
   key={index} 
   onMouseEnter={() => this.removeElementIcon(index)}
   onMouseLeave={hideRemoveElementIcon} 
   className={classes.gridClass}
>

   ...
</div>
```

In your function's set the `hoverIndex`,

```
removeElementIcon = (index) => {
    this.setState({removeElementIcon: true, hoverIndex: index});
};


hideRemoveElementIcon = () => {
    this.setState({removeElementIcon: false, hoverIndex:''});
};
```

And finally apply the condition,

```
{this.state.removeElementIcon && this.state.hoverIndex === index ?
    <IconButton className={classes.removeElement} color={"secondary"} arial-label={"remove element"} onClick={() => this.removeElement(value)}>
        <ClearIcon color={"error"}/>
    </IconButton>
    : null
}
```

or even short way

```
{this.state.removeElementIcon && this.state.hoverIndex === index &&
    <IconButton className={classes.removeElement} color={"secondary"} arial-label={"remove element"} onClick={() => this.removeElement(value)}>
        <ClearIcon color={"error"}/>
    </IconButton>
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pqbjng) with simple button.